# sentinelsat package in OSGeo4W (qgis)

Tags: python, sentinel, sentinelsat

I intend to download automatically Sentinel images, in a QGIS plugin. I found sentinelsat package and I install it in my OSGeo4W installation. However When I test in command line (in this case OSGeo4W Shell) this gives me an error:

sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 401 Unauthorized:

## HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource

**type** Status report

**message** *Full authentication is required to access this resource*

**description** *This request requires HTTP authentication.*

---

#### Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

I search and I found out that this error is related with the Python version. In OSGeo4W advanced installation I have python 2.7 and a folder with python 3.6. But when I installed the package was introduced in python 2.7.

What I can do to correct this error? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This error is likely not related to your Python version, as `sentinelsat` supports Python 2.7 and 3.4+. Have you tried to use the credentials at the Hub your are querying for the data?

Comment: Yes, and it works. My credentials are ok.